# Greatest common divisor VHDL FSM

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to implement the greatest common divisor in VHDL using an FSM.

These are the states

[image]

and some more details about the design

[image]

I made this implementation as described but I don't get the correct result during simulation

```
entity fsm is
    port (clk,rst: in std_logic; gt,eq,lt: in std_logic;
    sel,ld,sub: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    out_en: out std_logic);
end fsm;

architecture fsm of fsm is
    type STATES is (S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8);
    signal state: STATES;
begin
    process (clk, rst)
    begin
        if (rst='0') then 
            state<=S1;
        elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then
            case state is
                when S1 =>
                    sel(0) <= '1';
                    sel(1) <='0';                   
                    state <= S2;
                when S2 =>
                    ld(0) <= '1';
                    ld(1) <= '1';
                    state <= S3;
                when S3 =>
                    if(gt='1') then
                        state <= S4;
                    elsif(eq='1') then
                        state <= S6;
                    elsif(lt='1') then
                        state <= S7;
                    end if;
                when S4 =>
                    sub(0) <= '1';
                    state <= S5;
                when S6 =>
                    out_en <= '1';
                when S7 =>
                    sub(1) <= '1';
                    state <= S8;
                when S8 =>
                    sel(1) <= '1';
                    state <= S2;
                when S5 =>
                    sel(0) <= '0';
                    state <= S2;
                when others => null;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;

end fsm;
```

And at last this the wiring module. I will not post implementation of components here cause I think it straight forward what they are doing.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity gcd_calc is
    port (
        clk,rst: in std_logic;
        x_i,y_i: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        data_o: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end gcd_calc;

architecture struct of gcd_calc is

component mux8_2x1 
        port (sel: in std_logic;
            inp_a,inp_b: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            mout: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
    end component;  
component reg8 
        port (en,clk: in std_logic;
            inp: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            outp: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
    end component;

component cmp8 
        port (inp_a,inp_b: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            a_gt_b,a_eq_b,a_lt_b: out std_logic;
            outp: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
    end component;

component sub8
        port (en: in std_logic;
            inp_a,inp_b: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            outp: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
    end component;

component fsm
        port (clk,rst: in std_logic; gt,eq,lt: in std_logic;
            sel,ld,sub: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
            out_en: out std_logic);
    end component;
    signal muxx_o,regx_o,subx_o: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal muxy_o,regy_o,suby_o: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal cmp_o: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal x_sel,y_sel,x_ld,y_ld,x_sub,y_sub: std_logic;
    signal x_gt_y,x_eq_y,x_lt_y,data_en: std_logic;
begin
    mux_x: mux8_2x1 port map (x_sel,subx_o,x_i,muxx_o);
    mux_y: mux8_2x1 port map (y_sel,y_i,suby_o,muxy_o);
    reg_x: reg8 port map (x_ld,clk,muxx_o,regx_o);
    reg_y: reg8 port map (y_ld,clk,muxy_o,regy_o);
    cmp: cmp8 port map
        (regx_o,regy_o,x_gt_y,x_eq_y,x_lt_y,cmp_o);
    sub_x: sub8 port map (x_sub,regx_o,regy_o,subx_o);
    sub_y: sub8 port map (y_sub,regy_o,regx_o,suby_o);
    reg_out: reg8 port map (data_en,clk,cmp_o,data_o);
    ctrl: fsm port map
        (clk,rst,x_gt_y,x_eq_y,x_lt_y,
        sel(0)=>x_sel,sel(1)=>y_sel,
        ld(0)=>x_ld,ld(1)=>y_ld,
        sub(0)=>x_sub,sub(1)=>y_sub,out_en=>data_en);
end struct;
```

### EDIT

Simulation

[image]

Comment: Can you give the test case inputs and observed outputs? It might shed some light on what's going wrong.

Comment: @vhallac I've added simulation image. Hope this helps.

Comment: Since it goes to S6, the `eq` signal must get asserted at some point. You may want to look into its value during simulation as well. It may have something to do with the x and y registers' inital value before the first load triggering it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very fluent in VHDL, but it looks like you need to either reset the `ld` signals after state `S2`, or reset `sub` signals after `S4` and `S7`. There is one clock cycle where both the subtractors and the load signals are active as it stands.

Comment: Does the subtractor block latch its output when `en` is 0?

Comment: Yes blocks it. For some reason it goes to state 6 which will actually enable the output register. So the actual value is not already calculated and the output is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The code for `case S6` never sets `state` to another value, so it will "lock-up" and stay in that state.

Comment: I know. I fixed that. The problem is that it goes to state 6 when it not supposed to go.

Comment: @marcushatchenson: In that case, can I suggest you re-paste your actual code ... it may well be you've introduced something else since then.